# How do i apply a TranslateTransform on an existing 'Children'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm rewriting this question to try and make it clearer to people what ive done, trying to do etc.

I am involved in a project where im trying to make some visual displays. One display is a dial, and i pretty much got entire code from this link.

https://github.com/mesta1/WPF-Circular-Gauge/blob/master/CircularGauge/CircularGaugeDemoWPF/CircularGaugeDemoWPF.csproj

I am now trying to do a verticle guage, bit like below.
[image]

now ive modified the dial code so background  scale etc all works.

The issue im having is the moving indicator.

The dial code defines the dial in the xaml like the following.

```
<Path x:Name="Pointer" Stroke="#FFE91C1C" StrokeThickness="2" 
    Width="{TemplateBinding PointerLength}"  
    Height="{TemplateBinding PointerThickness}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    Data="M1,1 L1,10 L156,6 z" Stretch="Fill" 
    RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.5" 
    RenderTransform="{Binding RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PointerLength, 
    Converter={StaticResource pointerCenterConverter}}">
```

and in the .cs file controls its position like the following.

```
TransformGroup tg = pointer.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
RotateTransform rt = tg.Children[0] as RotateTransform;
rt.Angle = angleValue;
```

now as im only moving the indicator vertically up and down, i believe that i need a TranslateTransform. With the help of Sheridan. Ive changed my xaml to the following.

```
<Path x:Name="Pointer" Stroke="#FFE91C1C" StrokeThickness="2" 
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    Data="M 0,0 L 16,-5 L16,5 L0,0 z">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <TranslateTransform/>
             </TransformGroup>
         </Path.RenderTransform>
```

now im struggling with what my .cs needs to be to edit this. Currently im playing with

```
TransformGroup tg = pointer.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
TranslateTransform rt = tg.Children[0] as TranslateTransform;
rt.Y = -10;
```

this however throws error "Cannot set a property on object 'System.Windows.Media.TranslateTransform' because it is in a read-only state."

i have been advised again by Sheridan to try assigning a new object adn replacing the old. But what i seems to try either throws errors or has no effect.

Comment: Apparetly the `RenderTransform` value is created by a binding converter. You shouldn't manipulate that value in code behind. Either you create the transform directly in XAML, or you modify the binding so that the converter can directly create the desired value. Currently there is a `PointerLength` view model property. How should this be converted to a TranslateTransform? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: the above example is from a dial, so when the value changes, the pointer rotates around a set point to point at the new value (exactly like a speedo in a car), what im trying to do is create a display where the pointer moves on the x axis up and down pointing at the value. So im trying to change rotatetransform to translatetransform, my attempts so far though i keep getting tg null on TransformGroup tg = pointer.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;. I know i need to change the xaml i dont know what to.

Answer (score 0):

In order to transform a `UIElement`, you first need to apply a transformation element on it:

```
<Path ... >
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform />
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

If you are using a `TranslateTransform` as your `RenderTransform` property value, then you cannot cast it to a `RotateTransform`. You can find out more from the [`UIElement.RenderTransform` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) page on MSDN.

```
TransformGroup tg = pointer.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
// tg == null
```

Likewise, if you try to cast this property value to a `TransformGroup` without setting one, then you *will* get a `null` value:

```
<Path ... >
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform />
            <RotateTransform />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

You can find out more from the [`TransformGroup` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transformgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

...

```
TransformGroup tg = pointer.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
// tg is a TransformGroup
```

Comment: hi there, i implemented what u suggested and now tg obveiously isnt null anymore,                 TransformGroup tg = pointer.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
                TranslateTransform rt = tg.Children[0] as TranslateTransform;
                rt.X = 5;   when im trying to set rt.X im getting error "Cannot set a property on object 'System.Windows.Media.TranslateTransform' because it is in a read-only state."

Comment: That error just means *don't try to manipulate the existing `Transform`, instead create a new one and apply that to the `pointer.RenderTransform` property*.

Comment: i apologize in advance at my stupidity. But do you mean something like.               TransformGroup tg = pointer.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
                TranslateTransform rt = new TranslateTransform();
                rt.Y = 50;
                tg.Children.Add(rt);   this is giving me an error (not that ive looked at it yet, just want to make sure im on the right lines).

Comment: Your error tells you that your `TranslateTransform` is `readonly`. That means that you cannot change its value. So instead of trying to change its value, create a new `TranslateTransform` (using the values from the `readonly TranslateTransform` if necessary) and then *replace* the `readonly` object with your new object.

Comment: So this is what i believe i am doing:    TransformGroup tg = pointer.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;   <-- Gets the current pointer.   TranslateTransform rt = new TranslateTransform(); <-- Creates the new transform    rt.Y = 10;<--How much i want the pointer to move by   tg.Children.Add(rt); <-- Adding the new transform to the pointer. This is thorwing the error about readonly again.

Comment: TransformGroup tg = pointer.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
                TranslateTransform rt = new TranslateTransform();
                rt.Y = -10;
                tg.Children.Add(rt); give me the error Specified value of type 'System.Windows.Media.TransformCollection' must have IsFrozen set to false to modify.

Comment: If you're getting an error saying that the `TransformGroup` is `readonly`, then just create a new one of those too... what's the problem?

Comment: how do i apply the new transform group to the existing pointer?

Comment: Dude... really?  This is starting to get silly now. `pointer.RenderTransform = yourNewTransformGroup;`

Comment: again id like to apologize, i have a know it all sitting by me, saying "that wasn't the way to do it because it caused a memory leak as old TranslateTransform wernt deleted and it was only written over the top, increasing the memory, he jsut didnt know the proper way of doing it". as a result of this comment and the obveious lack of knowledge i have now moved my desk

Answer (score 0):

Please find the simple working code of dynamic Transform. I hope It will help you

WPF

```
<Window x:Class="WPFAnimationSample2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Ellipse x:Name="animateEllipse" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="61" Margin="99,78,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform  X="1" Y="1"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,256,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>


</Grid>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    void checkAnimation()
    {

        TransformGroup tg = animateEllipse.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
       TranslateTransform rt = tg.Children[3] as TranslateTransform;
       rt.X = rt.X+100;
       rt.Y = 100;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        checkAnimation();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        checkAnimation();
    }
}
```